# Has_many :through query about create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, has-many-through

I'm developing an app which has `users`, `venues` and `groups`.  I've created my models, and I'm pretty happy with them, but I'm getting a little confused with the controllers.  I mostly have `has_many :through` relationships.  For example I have a `user` model, a `venue` model and a `user_venue` model, which features a `user_id`, `venue_id` and `admin column`.  I want to automatically make the user an admin (increasing admin column by 1) when creating a venue, whilst also building the instance.  Other users will also be able to associate themselves with the venue without becoming an admin.

My models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues, through: :user_venues
  has_many :user_venues
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :user_venues
    has_many :user_venues
end

class UserVenue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :venues
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :venue_id, presence: true
end
```

What would be the best way for me to have a user create a venue and become an admin, and allow other users to create associations.  I assume once the initial venue is created, it will just be a matter of using the `user_venue` controller, I'm just struggling dealing with the abstracted models.  I also thought asking for some advice may ensure it's not a security nightmare through blagging it!  The `group` model would work in the same way.

I'm sure this will be an easy answer for someone!

**EDIT**

I've been working on this for another 4 hours now and still can't seem to see the solution, I can't even find it online.  So far my create definition of the `Venue Controller` looks like this:

```
def create
  admin = 1
  @user = current_user
  @venue = Venue.create(venue_params)
  @user_venue = UserVenue.new user_id: @user.id, venue_id: @venue.id, admin:  admin
  @user_venue.save
end
```

This unfortunately still only completes the `venues` table and not the `user_venues` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out... turns out I just needed to make the `belongs_to` relationships non-plural and use the following create method:

```
@venue = Venue.create(venue_params)
@venue.users << current_user
```

and it made the relationship.  Now I just need to work out the code to add an attribute to the `user_groups` table on create!...